# Why does scipy stats describe does not have median?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

It might be a naive question but I couldn't find a reasonable answer. Why the median is not included in the return of stats.describe ? Even kurtosis is included but why not median ?

Thanks

Comment: You can always call `np.median` directly.  Median doesn't always make sense, as with binary distributions, stepped values, etc.  Look at the code for `stats.describe`.  It does do any custom calculation; it's all delegated to to other functions such as `np.mean` and ones in the `stats` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot speak for the scipy stats.describe people, but the general answer is this: mean, variance, and even kurtosis can be computed in one or two O(n) passes through the data, while median requires an O(n*log(n)) sort.